# how to display and edit document in nodejs application

Tags: node.js

Need help to implement one requirement. i am working on node.js application and want to open different types documents e.g. pdf, word, xls etc in browser. also once document is open in viewer, user should be able to add some comments and freehand writing on it and save it in some format. ﻿

Comment: this is not related to nodejs.

Comment: it is related to nodejs as i am looking for some package in nodejs which can have to fullfill this requirement.

Comment: What option are you going for ?  1. Edit document in browser then update whole document at server side in single PUT call  or 2. Give an interface to user to edit file but actually edit the small chunks at server side with multiple PUT calls. This will involve what user needs to edit and where in parameters.

Comment: i will go for first option. user should be able to add some comments and freehand marking on the document. once user is done, he will hit save button and it will go to server.

Comment: so you will be sending whole edited document from browser to nodejs, for nodejs to only save and replace the existing document. Is this correct ?